# Как мне программно нажать на первый элемент списка в RecyclerView?

Tags: android

У меня есть RecyclerView. Как можно программно нажать на первый элемент списка? 
Я в адаптере сделал такую штуку:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(getItem(position).getUser().getUserInfo().getAvatarUrl(),
                holder.userAvatar, options, animateFirstDisplayListener);
        holder.userAvatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Observer.getInstance().send(MessageType.USER_LIST_ADAPTER_UN_MARK, Integer.valueOf(position));
                holder.choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.userAvatar.setBorderColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.user_border_color));
                Observer.getInstance().send(MessageType.USER_LIST_ADAPTER_ITEM, cashQueueList.get(position));
            }
        });
    }
```

…то есть при нажатии на элемент я меняю его внешний вид и отправляю кое что обсерверу. Но есть такой кейс, когда мне нужно установить какое то значение, привязанное к листу. И подсветить этот элемент тоже. То есть по-русски. Я тыкаю на элемент листа, он подсвечивается. Тыкаю на другой, он подсвечивается, а подсветка с первого убирается. А потом я не тыкаю в лист, а из другого места делаю действия, которые делает тыканье по элементу. И мне нужно подсветить в этот момент, первый элемент списка. В общем, как мне программно нажать на первый элемент списка в RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, но, возможно, это подкинет тебе какую-нибудь идею...

Мы можем хранить в `SparseBooleanArray` позицию выделенного элемента.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object>{

   private SparseBooleanArray checkedItem = new SparseBooleanArray();
   public MyAdapter(Context context, int resourse, List<Object> objects){
       super(context, 0, objects);
       for(int i = 0; i < objects.size; i++){
          checkedItem.put(i, false); // ничего не выделено
       }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      ViewHolder holder = null;
      if(convertView == null){
         //...типичное заполнение holder'a
      }

      if(checkedItem.get(position)
          holder.imageBackground = ваш бекграунд для выделенного элемента

   public void toggleChecked(int position){
      if(checkedItem.get(position))
         checkedItem.put(position, false);
      else
         checkedItem.put(position, true);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   public SparseBooleanArray getCheckedItem() { return checkedItem; }
}
```

Таким образом, манипуляциями со SparseBooleanArray можно выделять или убирать выделения с каких-то элементов. Это лишь пример, надеюсь, поможет придумать что-то